# Grafana Loki multi cluster setup | Federation

Tags: logging, kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

we have multiple cluster where we use Loki as logging service. now we are thinking of implement central logging service where we can see logs from all the cluster.
straight forward solution is deploy Loki stack and start pushing logs from all remote cluster. but this will incur data transfer cost.
we are thinking a more optimised solution like each cluster will have their own loki instance and central loki instance will connect to all the cluster. when ever they want to see logs user can login to central one and then can access logs.
Any thoughts or suggestion on this?

Comment: What did you end up going with? We currently have 1 instance per cluster and now I'm looking at how to configure a single grafana to pull from each one.

Comment: @justin.m.chase we were not able to comeUp with any solution till that time so we went with using S3. from Fluentd we were pushing logs to S3 and Loki simultaneously. Loki for last 1week retention and S3 for Historical need. and we had directory structure on S3 as per different deployments.